# Does CoreLocation framework required to connect to Core Bluetooth or Classic Bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, external-accessory

I have applications(Live and under maintenance) that connects with BLE device by Core bluetooth framework and Classic Bluetooth device by External Accessory framework.

Does enabling/implementing Core location framework helps in better connectivity with BLE or Classic Bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need CoreLocation to connect to a bluetooth device and using it should not do any improvements. You only need CoreLocation when you want to use the BLE device as an iBeacon for ranging and region monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

No. Connections are made entirely by the OS. What you do in your app doesn't impact how the system manages Bluetooth connections. It just impacts what requests you can make and what callbacks you can receive.